# Javascript indexOf not working with some value with text and number inside

Tags: javascript

I have these below javascript with `indexOf` function.

```
var arr = ['E8DB84DCA22F','C44F337FB12D','123456789ABC'];
var str = 'E8DB84DCA22F';
console.log(arr.indexOf(str));
```

When I tried to print the result, it's always show 0 result.

But if I do below function, it's show me result 1

```
var arr2 = ['example','foo','bar'];
var str2 = 'foo';
console.log(arr2.indexOf(str2));
```

My question, why on the first statement code the result is 0?

```js
var arr = ['E8DB84DCA22F','C44F337FB12D','123456789ABC'];
var str = 'E8DB84DCA22F';
console.log(arr.indexOf(str));

var arr2 = ['example','foo','bar'];
var str2 = 'foo';
console.log(arr2.indexOf(str2));
```

Comment: What's the problem? `0` is the correct index of the string you're looking for.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` returns the index of the element in the array. **In JavaScript, an array starts with [index 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering#:%7E:text=Martin%20Richards%2C%20creator%20of%20the,position%20p%20%2B%200%20in%20memory.).**
If the requested value is not found then the [index returned is -1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed. The first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index value equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array